# google analytics statistics

Tags: research, data, google, analytics

I am compiling a report for a client using google analytics. I have observed that the client has unusually good page view times (>5 mins) and excellent bounce rates (<25%).

I need to reference research data that validates my assertion that these figures are excellent compared to an industry standard (the industry is ecommerce and gaming).

**Can you direct me to any published research data that specifies normal bounce rates and page view times for this industry?**

Comment: If you choose to anonymously share your analytics data (in the data settings), then you will receive a benchmarking report from Google comparing your stats with websites in the same industry vertical - including page view times and bounce rates. Not sure of the frequency of reports though.

Comment: @RogerAttrill can you please be specific about where this setting is hidden? I can't find it!

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun It's hard to find for sure. Click *Admin* at top right shows a page where you can change settings. There's a breadcrumb trail at the top like "*All accounts > accountname >*". Click *All accounts*. Select the account of interest. There's a set of tabs (Properties, Users, Filters, Data sources, Account settings) Pick the *Account Settings* tab. It should show a section titled *Edit Analytics account* - with sub sections *General information* and **Data sharing settings**

Comment: I can understand you wanting this for bounce rate (or visits etc), but not for page view time - there can not be a good or bad figure for it as it's subjective. Does a person spend N minutes on a page because the content is good, an external reference is loading and freezes the browser or the user can't find the information they want! Remember, analytics show us what a person did, not why they did it!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is answered by the comments:

*If you choose to anonymously share your analytics data (in the data settings), then you will receive a benchmarking report from Google comparing your stats with websites in the same industry vertical - including page view times and bounce rates. Not sure of the frequency of reports though. – Roger Attrill Jun 20 at 12:10*

with further information about where it is from:

*@TorbenGundtofte-Bruun It's hard to find for sure. Click Admin at top right shows a page where you can change settings. There's a breadcrumb trail at the top like "All accounts > accountname >". Click All accounts. Select the account of interest. There's a set of tabs (Properties, Users, Filters, Data sources, Account settings) Pick the Account Settings tab. It should show a section titled Edit Analytics account - with sub sections General information and Data sharing settings – Roger Attrill Jun 25 at 20:28*